# Can't I add some columns to User model of django.contrib.auth.models?

Tags: python, django

I wanna add birthday & sex data column to User model of django.contrib.auth.models.However,I wrote forms.py like

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import User

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password1','password1','birthday','sex',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['birthday'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['sex'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

and when I run codes,django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (birthday) specified for User error happens.
I searched Django document,so I found kinds of User objects' field is limited like only username & email & password & is_staff & last_login etc.But now I wanna add birthday & sex data column, so how can I do it?Can't I do it?How should I write it?
Now by following a answer,I rewrote models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    sex = models.IntegerField()
```

I rewrote forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('username', 'email','password1','password1','birthday',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['birthday'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

I rewrote forms.py in the same way　before.But I got an error django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username, password1, email) specified for NewUser.How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

## update

In your `RegisterForm`, the `model` should be `NewUser`, and you may want to use `ModelForm`.

[Creating forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/)

## orginal

Change only the `form` is not enough, you need to start from `model`, I suggest you use the `OneToOneField` and add what you want to your own `model`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    sex = models.IntegerField()
```

and then you can create your own `form`.

[Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: thx ur anser.I updated my question, if u know something please help me

Comment: thx.But same error happens.I updated my question again.Could u check my code which is as same as ur intended code?

Comment: @user8817477 `username, password1, email` thess three should not in the `fields` because they not in `NewUser`, you can add them in `RegisterForm ` fields.

Comment: I cannot understand how to write ur code.How can I add username, password1, email to RegisterForm fields?Could u write ur intended code in ur answer?